# getBoundingClientRect() gives not a function error in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have a canvas Element in a component.
I have a separate js file where I get the element  by using 
`angular.element( document.querySelector('#id') )`.

Now what I want to know the Height and Width of the element.

Comment: see: https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the exact code you're running by I'm guessing it's something like this:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#id')).getBoundingClientRect()
```

You've wrapped the element in angular.element. `getBoundingClientRect` is a function on regular elements, so either don't wrap it, or use the element directly:

```
document.querySelector('#id').getBoundingClientRect()
angular.element(document.querySelector('#id'))[0].getBoundingClientRect()
```